# Table scheme to save different Time Series types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL table to hold People measures:

```
create table dbo.[State] ( 
  Id int identity not null constraint primary key clustered (Id),
  UserId int not null,
  Created datetime not null
  ChestPerimeter decimal (10, 2) null,
  HipsPerimeter decimal (10, 2) null,   
  Weight decimal (10, 2) null
  // Other measures 
)
```

Sometimes I log one measure, other times a few and others all.

Should I have this table or maybe two tables as follows:

```
create table dbo.Measure ( 
  Id int identity not null constraint primary key clustered (Id),
  UserId int not null,
  MeasureTypeId int not null,
  Created datetime not null
  Value decimal (10, 2) null,
)

create table dbo.MeasureType ( 
  Id int identity not null constraint primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar(20)
)
```

Where Measure Types are ChestPerimeter, Weight and so on ...

Or maybe other options like non int PK in MeasureType?

I will connect this to an API to log these values.

Comment: Why do you have a table to hold any type of measurement and ALSO have columns in a table named State to hold them again? Why is that table named State??? I would recommend not putting some measurements in one table and others in another table like that. Seems very strange. The real issue here though is that you have not actually posted a question. What are you expecting as a response to this post?

Comment: You didn't understand. The State table is one approach. The Measure + MeasureType is another approach. My question is: which one is better or if you would recommend a different one.

Comment: I would not recommend a table with a column for each measurement. That means at some point when you want to add a new one you have to change the table and all of the code that references it. What you have as your second option is known as the EAV (entity value attribute) pattern and might be well suited in this situation. Unless you know exactly what measurements need to be taken and they are not likely going to change.